# Use of paid as adjective

Tags: grammaticality

Can i use “paid” as an adjective while indicating an amount as is the case with the sentence below ?

> Plastic bag will be paid by 25 cent .

Or would it be better to say:

> Plastic bags will be charged at 25 cent.

Answer (score 2):

Neither sentence is grammatical, though I think I understand what you’re asking. Either *charge* or *cost* or *pay* would be an appropriate word here, and each one can be used as follows:

> In four months they will charge 25 cents per plastic bag.
>
> In four months customers will be charged 25 cents per plastic bag.
>
> In four months it will cost 25 cents to get a plastic bag.
>
> In four months customers will have to pay 25 cents per plastic bag.

Answer (score 2):

***Paid*** can be an adjective, used in contrast to *unpaid* - for example, you might be looking for *paid work*.

However, your suggested sentence doesn't use *paid* correctly. *Paid by* is saying that 25 cents will pay the bag. No-one is paying the bags everything. It would also still be a verb, in passive voice.

The usage of *charged* in your second example is something you might hear in general usage. Properly, it is a verb, and it should be "will be **charged for**". No dictionary I've found admits an adjective use of *charged* in that sense. However, usage in some dialects drops the *for* so *charged* ends up looking like an adjective. It isn't. Charged is only an adjective in reference to electrical charge - and then other things by analogy to electrical charge.

> Plastic bags will be charged for, at 25 cents.

That works, but it's clunky and shouldn't be used formally because it just sounds like you didn't think about it properly.

Try:

> There will be a charge of 25 cents per plastic bag.
>   You will have to pay 25 cents for each plastic bag.

There are other options, of course. A bewildering array. It's not a good place for using the passive voice, though.

Comment: Actually what i want to ask is that ;  while downloading an app  it says : for free for one month then for $5 per month. I wonder what the context is before “ for $5 per month”.

Comment: Trying to work out what the elision is there is tough. You obviously know what they mean, but they have said it very well. I would say "Free to use for your first month, costs £5 per month thereafter".

Comment: @languagelearner The elision is something like "*You can use the app* for free for one month, then for $5 per month". "You can use it *for* free" is informal English, and the "for" just emphasizes the "free". It would be more formal to say "You can use it free for one month..." without the "for".

Comment: It is true that you can use *paid* as the opposite of *free*- but I think you can only use it for less tangible things- “paid software,” “paid app,” “paid service”. You cannot say “paid bag”.

Comment: I didn't even think of it as an antonym for *free*, just for *unpaid*, which are used for different things. Yes, it can sometimes be an antonym for *free*, but not always. Tangible/intangible might be the deciding factor.